How to find performance bottleneck in SQL Server 2019 when sys.dm_os_wait_stats show the contrary?
There is an on prem SQL Server 2019. It is virtualized with VMware 7.0.3. The database shows weak performance:

it produces way more deadlocks than a system clone running on a local Docker setup.
The execution of basic SELECT Statements occasionally "hangs", meaning it takes extra seconds to complete though data is already visible.

To identify the bottleneck, a script to insert 10,000 rows into a table is executed on this database, a local Docker database, and a SQL Server RDS at Amazon RDS. sys.dm_os_wait_stats are cleared before the execution and compared afterwards.
It took 7s to complete the script on the on prem server (the one to investigate), 2s to complete on the AWS RDS, and ~50s on Docker.
However, the sum of wait_time_ms on on prem server is 164,796ms, while it is 6,920,143ms for the AWS RDS. For the Docker setup it is 7,246,454ms.
I/O is no bottleneck on the on prem server, since the numbers for WRITELOG, PAGEIOLATCH_EX, PAGEIOLATCH_SH, IO_COMPLETION, ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION are between 0 and 3ms.
(Reference)
This script is not memory intensive, so I doubt it is on memory. MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT and RESERVED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT block 0ms in total.
For CPU: I don't expect a lack of CPU because these are the only wait types showing waits:
XE_TIMER_EVENT - 10012
REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH - 5012
SOS_WORK_DISPATCHER - 21
Am I wrong?
I got a hint that the VM might be under-provisioned with CPU and that this is not reflected in the wait statistics.
So, here are the questions:

How to test if the server is under-provisioned on VM-level?
Any other ideas on how to identify the bottleneck?

The task is not to improve the queries, but to make the database server handle all existing queries in a performant way. For this, I need to understand the bottleneck slowing down the execution of queries.
This is the execution plan to add 100 lines with the following statement:
declare @i int
set @i = 1
while (@i < 101)
 begin
   begin tran
    insert T1(id) values(@i)
   commit
   if (@i % 1000) = 0
     raiserror('1000 Zeilen hinzugefügt', 0, 1) with nowait
   set @i = @i + 1
 end

Reduced the query to 100 rows because 10,000 lines broke SSMS.

@ERoss Ah well, now I understand. This is a faulty way to test, and won't really expose your issue with your other queries. Running 10,000 individual inserts from SSMS is of course going to incur some client-side hiccups that'll probably contribute to the 7 seconds execution time you saw and be irrelevant to troubleshooting your other queries. It's also perfectly reasonable to expect SSMS to run 10,000 individual inserts statements and the server to process them 1 by 1 sequentially in 7 seconds. You're better off providing the execution plan of a real query that's running slower than expected.

Thank you. Now reading your explanation it makes perfectly sense.

Do you know if the execution plan of a single query reflects underprovisioned virtualized hardware, like a lack of CPU during runtime?

It possibly can, yes. The wait stats will tell you why that query is running slowly. If your biggest bottleneck is under-provisioned hardware like lack of CPU, then that'll be the biggest wait type in the execution plan of the specific query that's slow, most likely.
